# Django not using local machine time

Tags: django, datetime

I will preface my question by saying that I have found a work around and am more interested in the why Django is doing what it is doing. I am new to Django and am using it within a virtual environment. When I call a simple datetime.now() the result is in UTC and not my machine's local time. I believe this is the behavior on Linux and Macs while PCs will return the machine local time. In other python based frameworks I have used in a virtual environment the machine local time is returned. As I said, just curious as to why Django is doing what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation on timezones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/): Django uses UTC by default but that can be changed by modifying the value of `TIME_ZONE` in your `settings.py` file. But think carefully before you store anything other than UTC in your database. It's a best practice to store times in UTC and then modify the display on the front-end based on the user's selected timezone or the site's default timezone.